# No MiniTest rake tasks in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rake, minitest

I am trying to create a new Rails 4.1.4 app (Ruby 2.1.2) utilizing minitest. After following the instructions shown below, when I run `rake -T` it does not show any minitest rake tasks.

Is there something I am missing here?

1) Add to `Gemfile`

```
group :test do
  gem 'minitest-rails'
  gem 'minitest-rails-capybara'
  gem 'minitest-colorize'
  gem 'minitest-focus'
end
```

2) `bundle`

3) Add to `test/test_helper.rb` (after `require "rails/test_help"`)

```
require 'minitest/rails'
require 'minitest/rails/capybara'
require 'minitest/focus'
require 'minitest/colorize'
```

4) Remove `require 'rails/all'` from `config/application.rb`

5) Add to `config/application.rb`

```
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require 'rake/testtask'
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
require "minitest/rails/railtie"
```

I then run `rake -T` and it comes back with a list of rake tasks which does not include any minitest tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 2.0 minitest-rails does not add `minitest` rake tasks. The default rails `test` rake tasks are used. See the section on running tests in the [README](https://github.com/blowmage/minitest-rails#running-tests).

Also, if you are including the minitest-rails Railtie in your `config/application.rb`, then you shouldn't place the dependency in the `:test` group in your `Gemfile`.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused about your question. Are you trying to add custom minitest tasks, or just normal ones such as rake test? Rails 4 should already come with minitest as a dependency for ActiveSupport. In your Gemfile.lock file, check to make sure if minitest is under activesupport. Mine looks like this:

```
activesupport (4.1.0)
  i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.9)
  json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
  minitest (~> 5.1)
```

If not, try running bundle install to see if all the dependencies are installed.

Finally, (though you probably know this) the tasks won't say minitest. They will be 'test', like 'rake test', so if that's what you're confused about (I can't really tell based on the question) then just make sure rake test works and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe since you put `gem 'minitest-rails'` in the test group, and rake by default sets `RAILS_ENV=development`, you need to do something like:

```
RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake -T
```

or just take `gem 'minitest-rails'` out of the test group, since the line `require "minitest/rails/railtie"` in application.rb will always try to load it anyway.